# VS Code and Javascript: Getting Started

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am more of database professional and recently did JavaScript & Angular JS courses. I used the editor "Brackets"; It was easy to run the Javascript code using Bracket as all the infrastructure is set by by default in Brackets. 
Recently installed the VS Code and planning to start writing JavaScript & Angular JS code using VS Code. I installed all recommended extensions needed. Since not familiar with VS Code, I am trying to know how can i ecuet a JavaScript code consisting of an index.html, app.js and invoking this in chrome browser. Need to the steps to start from scratch

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: This is a very broad question. You may want to use Node.JS as well and other things. I recommend you to check https://code.visualstudio.com/docs and go from there.

Comment: if you want to use a server on client side to run code on localhost you can use live-server or light-server

Answer (score 0):

Open VScode where you want to do your project whatsoever, at the left side there will be the list of files residing in your current directory, add a new file named "app.js" and fill it with all the js contents you like and again add a new file "index.html" and add the html code in it, now right click on "index.html" and select open with google chrome and you are done then. VSCode is just an editing material like sublime, notepad++ etc.